# python 'int' has no '__getittem__' error

Tags: python, typeerror, magic-methods

I'm trying to receive certain contents of a list called *eeprom*, and save them under a list called *bytes*.

```
class Parameter (object):
    def __init__ (self, eeprom, *address):
        self.eeprom = eeprom
        self.bytes = list()
        for a in address:
            a = int(a, 16)
            byte = eeprom[a]                 # here lies the problem
            self.bytes.append(byte)

sthg = Parameter(eeprom, "0x00B9", "0x00BA")
```

Whenever I run the script, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Does anyone has any idea of why this happens? If I write this on the interpreter it works, it is only when I run it as a module that I get this error.

Comment: what is `eeprom` here? and post the traceback.

Comment: Most probably you're sending ``eeprom`` as an int, which cannot be subscripted like you do in ``eeprom[a]``

Comment: You sent an `int` instead of a `list` for the `eeprom` parameter.

Comment: A list of length = 2048 with its values written in decimal, e.g. eeprom[0] = 13, eeprom[2047] = 255

Comment: @user2546407 nop! it's not a list, you're passing it an integer.

Comment: You guys are probably right, just saw that I got *eeprom* as a class, with which i use *__getitem__* , *__setitem__* , and *__repr__* . I'm probably doing something wrong in there, thank you very much for the orientation!

Answer (score 3):

When you are instantiating Parameter you are most likely passing an int in for the eeprom arguments instead of a list. You are probably doing the equivalent of

```
sthg = Parameter(1, "0x00B9", "0x00BA")
```

when you should be doing

```
sthg = Parameter([1,2,3,4], "0x00B9", "0x00BA")
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are instantiating your class you should pass eeprom as a list argument but you are passing it as a int argument.
int object do not have any `__getitem__()` function that is why you can not access it using `[]` (indexing), so you should be having any iterable as a eeprom argument..

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parameter (object):
    def __init__ (self, eeprom, *address):
        self.eeprom = eeprom
        self.bytes = list()
        for a in address:
            a = int(a,16)
            byte = eeprom[a]                 # here lies the problem
            self.bytes.append(byte)


eeprom = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
sthg = Parameter(eeprom, "0x0009")
```

**eeprom should be List object not integer an integer**

Example:

```
eeprom = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```